# Horizontal Layout in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I am building an app using Polymer. I've found the layout system tricky. Currently, I'm trying to layout some buttons so that they look like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                   [ok]                   [more info]  [cancel] |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The gap to the left of the "ok" button is 25% of the entire width of the page. The remaining 75% is used for the buttons. In an attempt to build the above, I put together [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SuKzIS5AD3098cs9Kz8K?p=preview), which includes the following code:

```
<paper-toolbar class="statusbar">
  <div style="width:25%;"></div>
  <div style="width:75%;" class="fit">
    <div class="layout horizontal flex" style="padding-bottom:12px;">
      <paper-button raised>OK</paper-button>

      <div class="flex"></div>
      <paper-button raised>More Info</paper-button>                            
      <paper-button raised>Cancel</paper-button>                                
    </div>
  </div>
</paper-toolbar>
```

For some reason, the "25%" padding to the left isn't taken. I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you looked at the `iron-flex-layout` element? [This](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) guide should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its recommended to use border to see what you are trying to build using div blocks. I added `margin:1px solid green` to your `25%` and `margin:1px solid yellow` to the 75% div block and this is what you have so far.

[image]

I changed your code taking advantage of [Flexbox layout with iron-flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout)

Here is the update  [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9omHD3G0gQnXNErPHPeX?p=preview)

```html
<paper-header-panel class="flex" mode="seamed">
  <paper-toolbar>
    <div>Hello</div>
  </paper-toolbar>

  <div class="fit content">
    <div style="height:100%;">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>

  <paper-toolbar class="statusbar">

    <div class="layout horizontal flex" style="width:100%">
      <div class="layout vertical flex-1 center center" style="border:1px solid green">
        <paper-button raised>OK</paper-button>
      </div>
      <div class="layout horizontal flex-4 " style="border:1px solid yellow">
        <span class="flex"></span> 
        <!-- take all space-->
        <paper-button raised>More Info</paper-button>
        <paper-button raised>Cancel</paper-button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </paper-toolbar>
</paper-header-panel>
```